# Hello, I am using swift and I am trying to change a label of a collection view cell when the a collection view cell is selected

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I have here my collection view controller and when I click on the collection view cell it is updating between true and false but my label is not updating from added to not added. any help would be greatly appreciated I have been at this for 4 days. I have tried reading the apple documentation and it doesn't give examples as to how to accomplish this with using a boolean value. What I want to happen is for the Label atop my collection view cell label to change from added to not added when the collection view cell has been pressed. I know it is working because when I tested it with print statements when I press the collection view cell it changes back and forth from true to false. I am just having trouble with the label changing from added to not added with it.

```
import UIKit


class ShoppingListCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    var shoppingItemController = ShoppingItemController()

    var shoppingItemCollectionViewCell = ShoppingItemCollectionViewCell()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        shoppingItemCollectionViewCell.updateViews()


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "ShoppingListDetailSegue" {

          guard let shoppingListDetailVC = segue.destination as? ShoppingListDetailViewController else {
                return 
            }

        }

        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }


    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        return shoppingItemController.shoppingItems.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ShoppingItemCell", for: indexPath) as? ShoppingItemCollectionViewCell else {
            fatalError("Collection view cell identifier is wrong or the cell is not a ShoppingItemCollectionViewCell")
        }

        // Configure the cell
        let shoppingListItem = shoppingItemController.shoppingItems[indexPath.item]
        cell.imageView.image = shoppingListItem.image
        cell.shoppingItemLabel.text = shoppingListItem.imageName
        if shoppingListItem.added == true {
            cell.hasBeenAddedLabel.text = "Added"
        } else {
            cell.hasBeenAddedLabel.text = "Not Added"
        }
        return cell
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        var chosenItem = shoppingItemController.shoppingItems[indexPath.item]
        chosenItem.added = !chosenItem.added
        shoppingItemController.shoppingItems[indexPath.item] = chosenItem
        if chosenItem.added == true {
            chosenItem.updateViews()
        }


        print(chosenItem.added)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to get the cell from `cellForItem(at:)` method inside the `didSelectItemAt` method and update the label text to your desired string:

```swift
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ShoppingItemCollectionViewCell
    var chosenItem = shoppingItemController.shoppingItems[indexPath.item]
    chosenItem.added.toggle()
    cell.label.text = chosenItem.added ? "Added" : "Not Added"
}
```

Comment: Omg that worked! Thank you so much so then should I just twist the logic a bit so that it switches back when selected again?